# How to define in @Route with #name

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.3, symfony-routing

I'm new with Symfony 3, and I'm trying to figure how to implement in my `@Route` with #order just only to show the exact position of the render page... but when I define in my `@Route` this way:

```
 @Route("/{orderNumber}/details{_attr}" <--- this part
```

or with:

```
 @Route("/{orderNumber}/details#order" <--- this part
```

It doesn't work the code is:

**From the controller**

```
/**
 * @Route("/{orderNumber}/details{_attr}", 
 *
 * @param string $orderNumber
 *
 * @return Response
 */
```

**From the html.twig**

```
<div class="order container" id="order"> <--- to show at this part
 <div class="order-header row">
  <div class="order-title col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-8">
```

So... I need help in this point because I don't have idea how to implement correctly.

Comment: You shouldn't use anchors in your routes - what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Use $this->generateUrl('name') . '#' . 'whatever'

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass default value to route for example here:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#advanced-routing-example

Else if you want just `html hash link` You don't need to pass default value to your route. Because Browser can automaticly scroll to your html code where you `ID`.

FOR EXAMPLE HERE:

http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/a.html#a-tags